# How to create a percentage stack plot for unequal group size in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data, stacked-chart, stackedbarseries

I have 2 groups namely "A" and "B" of unequal sample size. The size of "A" is 19 and the size of "B" is 15 total size of data being 34. They have a categorical variable named "Drug1" to indicate how many people of group A and B takes that drug so the values of the "Drug1" variables are YES and NO.

How do I create a percentage stack plot where I can show both groups and the number of people of each who take the drug and who do not take the drug in percentage stacked over each other? I would also like to annotate the percentage value in the bar

This is a sample of how the input looks like:

```
dat1<- data.frame(id=1:n,
Group=sample(c("A", "B"), 6, replace = TRUE) , 
Drug1=sample(c("Yes", "No"), 6, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)

dataset <- data.frame(
  Groups = as.factor(sample(c("A", "B"), 30, replace = T)),
  Drug_1 = as.factor(sample(c("Yes", "No"), 30, replace = T))
)


df_tbl <- table(dataset)

df_tbl <- round(100 * prop.table(df_tbl, margin = 1), 2)

df_tbl <- as.data.frame(df_tbl)

ggplot(df_tbl, aes(fill = Drug_1, y = Freq, x = Groups)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") + 
  labs(y = "Percent") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), position = "stack", vjust = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Stacked barplots of percentages may be obtained easily by converting both variables to factor (e.g. `df$Drug1 = as.factor(df$Drug1)`) and plotting them against each other with the basic `plot()` function:

```
plot(df$Group,df$Drug1,xlab="Group of Participand",ylab="Drug taken")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But does it take into account the unequal sample size of both groups? Also is it possible to annotate the percentage value in the fill?

Comment: What do you mean by "take into account"? It's a proportional plot, so both groups have 100% in total and you see the shares. The group size is irrelevant. If you want to add labels, it takes some more lines to add the text. If you want a beautiful plot, better go for the `ggplot2` solution.